# I am trying to put just and only 3 special characters(@ # $) in a password in javasript/html

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The question is like that:
i. The password must be exactly 8 characters long.
ii. It must contain at least one letter, one number, and no special character.
iii. The only special characters allowed are: @ # $
My answer:

What is the way to assign only these (@ # $) special character not more than those?

Comment: my answer : <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw"
      pattern="^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$]).{8,8})$" minlength="8" required> it still gives me more that those 3 assign characters how can i fix it to just have 3 special character(@#$)

Comment: play around on regex website in order to fit your criteria

Comment: This is not a good idea -- anyone can just delete the JS that validates this and make a password without them

Comment: @LoganDevine True, but you should still validate and tell the user what's wrong before sending a request to the server. Basic UX. Honestly, I don't know why this thread is downvoted - it's clear of what's being asked, and Dayya added a solution of their own as well.

Comment: @RickardElimää I can see how that would improve validation speed -- so you would validate it client side and then also serverside on the actual HTTP request?

Comment: @LoganDevine Yeah, always. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d@#\$]{8,8}
```

The trick is that you need to include them all again at the very end `[a-zA-Z\d@#\$]` instead of using a `.`

You can try it out in https://regexr.com/

Just copy paste the following in the field to check if the regex is correct:

```
qwertyui
123rtyui
12345@#$
qwert@#$
123Ba@#!
123Ba@#%

123Ba@#a
123Ba@#$sd
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$])(?=.{8,})
```

- `^`  The password string will start this way
- `(?=.*[a-z])`    The string
  must contain at least 1 lowercase alphabetical character
- `(?=.*[A-Z])`    The string must contain at least 1 uppercase
  alphabetical character
- `(?=.*[0-9])`    The string must contain at least
  1 numeric character
- `(?=.*[@#$])`    The string must contain at least
  one special character
- `(?=.{8,})`  The string must be eight characters
  or longer

Also I wouldn't recommend you to make this verification on the front-end because it's easy to hack it.